# SQS createQueue results in NonExistentQueue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm attempting to create a queue in SQS, but when I do I get the error `AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue`.

This error doesn't make sense because it isn't listed as a possible error on their documentation page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error was that when creating my queue I specified a `deadLetterTargetArn` as a `RedrivePolicy` when creating the queue

`sqs.createQueue({
  Attributes: {
    RedrivePolicy: {
      deadLetterTargetArn: "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<account_number>:dead-letter"
    }
  }
})`

It was the dead-letter queue that didn't exist, something that the error message doesn't say.